# First "space walk" described in fiction?

Tags: history-of, spaceship, space-exploration

When I search for this, I am only getting hits about the real 1965 space walk.

As mentioned in the question about the vacuum of space, it seems to me that the early works about journeys to Luna primarily concern themselves with the destination, not the trip itself.

I suspect that it was understood by science that one could exit a vehicle in space and float along side it because the human had the same velocity as the vehicle, but I wonder if Verne would have grasped this fully.

In Wells, because of the imaginary Cavorite, I am not sure it is clear what would happen to an astronaut outside of a capsule made of this stuff -- I think it could be argued that the vehicle would continue to accelerate due to the influences of antigravity and the human would rapidly get left behind -- a space walk in Wells therefore would not have been attempted by the travelers.

Indeed, the travelers in both of these stories would have had little reason to leave the confines of their ship -- it might be a long time before an author came up with a reason for a space walk although I think by the 1930s or so, travelers were leaving vehicles to, for example, enter other vehicles. Asimov has also the story C-Chute which features a space walk.

Comment: > "one could exit a vehicle in space and float along side it because the human had the same velocity as the vehicle, but I wonder if Verne would have grasped this fully"
>
I remember there was a scene in the book **Round The Moon** by **Jules Verne**, where they threw out the body of dead dog outside of the projectile/capsule (https://www.literature.org/authors/verne-jules/round-the-moon/chapter-05.html), finding it later still floating outside (https://www.literature.org/authors/verne-jules/round-the-moon/chapter-07.html)

Comment: I vaguely remember a spacewalk in Edison's Conquest of Mars by Garrett P. Serviss in 1898

Comment: @p4ulie I thought of that, too. The act of throwing the dog out was impossible, though, because they would not be able to open the porthole, or they would not be able to close it, depending on which way it opened. If Verne had invented the air lock, that would have been quite an accomplishment.

Answer (score 33):

There is a space walk scene in [*Edison's Conquest of Mars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20773) (1898) by Garrett P. Serviss.  (Note that for some reason ISFDb barely notes the original 1898 serialization.)

The following quotes are from the [Project Gutenberg copy](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19141/19141-h/19141-h.htm) of the story, which is transcribed from the original 1898 printing.

There are space suits of a fashion:

> While it was the intention to remain as much as possible within the cars, yet since it was probable that necessity would arise for occasionally quitting the interior of the electrical ships, Mr. Edison had provided for this emergency by inventing **an air-tight dress constructed somewhat after the manner of a diver's suit, but of much lighter material. Each ship was provided with several of these suits, by wearing which one could venture outside the car even when it was beyond the atmosphere of the earth.**  ("Perpetual Night!")

The space suits have thermal control and a self-contained atmosphere:

> Provision had been made to meet the terrific cold which we knew would be encountered the moment we had passed beyond the atmosphere—that awful absolute zero which men had measured by anticipation, but never yet experienced—by a simple system of producing within the air-tight suits a temperature sufficiently elevated to counteract the effects of the frigidity without. By means of long, flexible tubes, air could be continually supplied to the wearers of the suits, and **by an ingenious contrivance a store of compressed air sufficient to last for several hours was provided for each suit**, so that in case of necessity the wearer could throw off the tubes connecting him with the air tanks in the car. Another object which had been kept in view in the preparation of these suits was the possible exploration of an airless planet, such as the moon. ("Terrific Cold Anticipated.")

The ships have airlocks to exit into space:

> In the meantime Mr. Edison had been donning his air-tight suit. Before we could clearly comprehend his intention **he had passed through the double-trapped door which gave access to the exterior of the car without permitting the loss of air**, and was standing upon what served as the deck of the ship.   ("The Battle Commences")

A longer passage describes a free-fall spacewalk during the voyage to Mars, which actually has reasonable science:

> One of the most startling experiences that I have ever had was one day when we were navigating space about half way between the earth and Mars. I had stepped outside the car with Lord Kelvin, both of us, of course, wearing our air-tight suits. We were perfectly well aware what would be the consequence of detaching ourselves from the car as we moved along. We should still retain the forward motion of the car, and of course accompany it in its flight. There would be no falling one way or the other. The car would have a tendency to draw us back again by its attraction, but this tendency would be very slight, and practically inappreciable at a distance.
>
> **Stepping Into Space.**
> "I am going to step off," I suddenly said to Lord Kelvin. "Of course I shall keep right along with the car, and step aboard again when I am ready."
>
> "Quite right on general principles, young man," replied the great savant, "but beware in what manner you step off. Remember, if you give your body an impulse sufficient to carry it away from the car to any considerable distance, you will be unable to get back again, unless we can catch you with a boathook or a fishline. Out there in empty space you will have nothing to kick against, and you will be unable to propel yourself in the direction of the car, and its attraction is so feeble that we should probably arrive at Mars before it had drawn you back again."
>
> All this was, of course, perfectly self-evident, yet I believe that but for the warning word of Lord Kelvin, I should have been rash enough to step out into empty space with sufficient force to have separated myself hopelessly from the electrical ship.
>
> **A Reckless Experiment.**
> As it was, I took good care to retain a hold upon a projecting portion of the car. Occasionally cautiously releasing my grip, I experienced for a few minutes the delicious, indescribable pleasure of being a little planet swinging through space, with nothing to hold me up and nothing to interfere with my motion.

[image: Drawing of the narrator and Lord Kelvin in their space suits floating in space outside the car.]

Comment: I made this an answer a whole minute before you, but you get an upvote and i don't , life is so unfair( your's a better answer obviously tho)

Comment: Very nice! An amazing book, despite the semi-plagiarism of Wells -- seems like that is too harsh, it is certainly a very different work. I love that Edison and Kelvin are actually characters. They should make a faithful "steam-punk" movie from this, I mean big budget with Kelvin's  and others' background gone into. Can't wait to see this.

Comment: @releseabe It's part of a subgenre known as [Edisonade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edisonade)s if you want to read up on them more and it's apparently a sequel to an unauthorized adaptation of Wells.

Comment: @ssokolow: thanks very much.

Answer (score 13):

As Far as I can remember, the first space walk I remember is [Conquest of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison%27s_Conquest_of_Mars) by Garrett P. Serviss first published in 1898.

> At one point, the book's narrator describes the awesome feeling of stepping outside the ship and experiencing weightlessness thanks to his all-body leather condom; or, as he put it, "the delicious, indescribable pleasure of being a little planet swinging through space, with nothing to hold me up and nothing to interfere with my motion."

I know this answer fells inspired by @Winchell Chung's comment but I already knew this one and since that user hadn't made an answer I did.

[Source](https://www.cracked.com/article_19949_the-6-most-important-sci-fi-ideas-were-invented-by-hack.html)

Comment: Your memory goes back a long time!! How young were you in 1898?

Answer (score 7):

If I remember it correctly after reading it 30 years ago, in the book *[By Rocket to the Moon](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/10151572)* (1928, German original name: *Hans Hardts Mondfahrt*) by [Otto Willi Gail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Willi_Gail), there is a scene where the travelers venture outside of the rocket ship in the (modified?) diving suit, using handguns shooting blanks as a method of propelling themselves around.

I do not have a copy on hand, maybe somebody could post an excerpt, if I am correct?

Comment: Interesting, especially the handgun propulsion. Note that liquid-fueled rockets were newish in those days. I would have guessed compressed air would have occurred to a writer instead -- compressed air technology is surprisingly old: Lewis and Clark had a 30 shot air rifle that could kill a deer and this was not even new in 1803.

Answer (score 4):

[Konstantin Tsiolkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky), a Russian engineer who developed much of the theory of rocketry (such as the [Tsiolkovsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)), also sometimes wrote educational essays and stories, including an 1895 piece called [Константин Циолковский](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1301719) later translated into English as [Dreams of Earth and Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1521016). The English version was published in the collection [The Call of The Cosmos](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?310519) which is available on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/mode/2up), with Dreams of Earth and Sky beginning on [p. 52](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/page/52/mode/2up). The piece is a mix of non-fictional essayistic writing and short fictional pieces providing illustrations of the non-fictional ideas he discussed, and in one of the fictional sections, titled "In the Asteroid Belt" (beginning on [p. 99](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/page/98/mode/2up)), the narrator talks about how the alien inhabitants of the airless asteroid have provided him with a pressurized spacesuit ([p. 100](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/page/100/mode/2up)):

> when I wanted to see how they lived, they covered me up closely without affecting the shape of my body or interfering with my freedom of motion; the covering was a rather thin membrane which protected my body against the dangerous absence of atmospheric pressure; they supplied me with oxygen-containing vessels and various other apparatuses which were connected with my body and for some time took the place of air and food.

Later on [p. 111](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/page/110/mode/2up) he describes how in addition to living on the surface, the aliens have built a habitable orbiting ring around the asteroid:

> The many millions who populate the planet live on it only part of the time; most of them, in pursuit of light and room for themselves, form—with their machines, apparatus and structures—a moving swarm around it shaped like the ring around Saturn, only relatively larger.

And on [p. 112](https://archive.org/details/tsiolkovsky-the-call-of-the-cosmos/page/112/mode/2up) the narrator goes on to describe how he visited the ring:

> I travelled together with my house and all my house furnishings, as built for me by the inhabitants of the asteroid. I was thus able, whenever I wanted, to enjoy the atmosphere and everything I was accustomed to. As soon as I grew tired of my customary way of living, I donned my "skin" and attached all the equipment I needed for living in a vacuum and wandered about in it, quite imperturbed.

That last line, though brief and not elaborated on, does seem to suggest spacewalking in a vacuum far from the surface of any natural body.

Comment: He was a great man who overcame many disadvantages to pioneer much of modern space travel.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting description of space-suits and a spacewalk in [*The Skylark of Space*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/20869/pg20869-images.html) by E. E. Doc Smith, published as a magazine serial 1928, re-published with modifications in 1946.

> After an interminable silence, DuQuesne drew himself out of his seat.
> He took a long inhalation, deposited the butt of his cigarette
> carefully in his ash tray, and made his way to his room. He returned
> with three heavy fur suits provided with air helmets, two of which he
> handed to the girls, who were huddled in a seat with their arms around
> each other. These suits were the armor designed by Crane for use in
> exploring the vacuum and the intense cold of dead worlds. Air-tight,
> braced with fine steel netting, and supplied with air at normal
> pressure from small tanks by automatic valves, they made their wearers
> independent of surrounding conditions of pressure and temperature.
>
> "The next thing to do," DuQuesne stated calmly, "is to get the copper
> off the outside of the ship. That is the last resort, as it robs us of
> our only safeguard against meteorites, but this is the time for
> last-resort measures. I'm going after that copper. Put these suits on,
> as our air will leave as soon as I open the door, and practically an
> absolute vacuum and equally absolute zero will come in."

DuQuesne doesn't actually get to carry out this plan, as they are rescued by another vessel piloted by the girls' boyfriends.  Their spacewalk would instead be a transfer from one ship to the other. We have this description of the depressurization:

> Hastily returning to the main compartment, he briefly informed the
> girls as to what had happened. All three donned the suits and
> stationed themselves at the upper opening. Rapidly, but with unerring
> precision, the two ships were brought into place and held together by
> the attractor. As the doors were opened, there was a screaming hiss as
> the air of the vessels escaped through the narrow crack between them.
> The passengers saw the moisture in the air turn into snow, and saw the
> air itself first liquefy and then freeze into a solid coating upon the
> metal around the orifices at the touch of the frightful cold
> outside—the absolute zero of interstellar space, about four hundred
> sixty degrees below zero in the every-day scale of temperature. The
> moisture of their breath condensed upon the inside of the double
> glasses of their helmets, rendering sight useless.

The transfer is made by DuQuesne tossing the girls through the open door of the other ship -- lest they touch the freezing-cold metal of the hull -- and then diving through it himself.  Whether that counts as a "spacewalk" I will leave to the reader.

[image: the rescue, with fur space suits]

> Dorothy pushed the other girl ahead of her. DuQuesne seized her and
> tossed her lightly through the doorway in such a manner that she would
> not touch the metal, which would have frozen instantly anything coming
> into contact with it. Seaton was waiting. Feeling a woman's slender
> form in his arms, he crushed her to him in a mighty embrace, and was
> astonished to feel movements of resistance, and to hear a strange,
> girlish voice cry out:
>
> "Don't! It's me! Dorothy's next!"
>
> Releasing her abruptly, he passed her on to Martin and turned just in
> time to catch his sweetheart, who, knowing that he would be there and
> recognizing his powerful arms at the first touch, returned his embrace
> with a fierce intensity which even he had never suspected that she
> could exert. They stood motionless, locked in each other's arms, while
> DuQuesne dove through the opening and snapped the door shut behind
> him.
>
> The air-pressure and temperature back to normal, the cumbersome suits
> were hastily removed, and Seaton's lips met Dorothy's in a long,
> clinging caress.